Adding a Calcualted column to a site content type for a custom list which contain 1,200,000 items
I have a custom list which contain around 1,200,000 items. and this custom list is linked to a site content type. now inside the site content type i tried to add a calculated column of type Date/Time , where i define the formula which is :-
[DueDate] + 750/(24*60)
But when i submitted the calculated column info >> i got this page for more than 4 hours now:-

and the column did not get added to the site content type... so is this just a time matter? or i will never be able to add calculated column to a large list?

You can try using PnP PowerShell to add a calculated column:
#Parameter
$SiteURL = "https://crescent.sharepoint.com/sites/pmo"
$ListName= "Projects"
  
#Connect to PnP Online
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Interactive
 
#Add a calculated column to list
Add-PnPField -List $ListName -Type Calculated -InternalName "Buffer" -DisplayName "Buffer" -Formula "=[Budget]*0.10"

Reference: SharePoint Online: Add Calculated Column to List using PowerShell
